# Spring Framwork Authentication using dynamic role and also give permission dynamically

Tags: spring-security

How i can manage dynamic role security authentication and also give permission and granted authority using roles stored in database.

Comment: https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring-security-dynamic-authorization-and-authentication. i have implemented similar to it

Comment: In this project will i authorize all JSP using multiple roles list fetch from database.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom AuthenticationProvider.
In authenticate(...) method you can join multiple roles in authority set.
A simple example to implement custom AuthenticationProvider see 
[there](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-custom)